# JavaScript global variable to store kml model object

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I'm developing a webpage to display google earth and a kml object. There will be two frames, one is the earth + kml object, the other is to display kml object's info like altitude, latitude, longitude...

I'm done with load the kml object and display its info on the page. Now, I want to add some events to control the kml object with keyboard, to move it and reflect all the changes in coordination onto the display frame.

In order to do that, I create my own object:

```
    //Constructor for object ModelInfo
function ModelInfo(name) {
    var me = this;
    me.model = null;
    me.name = name;
    me.lon = 120.89250214028388;
    me.lat = 22.17480037801846;
    me.alt = 15.00;
    me.heading = 0.0;
    me.tilt = 0.0;
    me.roll = 0.0;
    me.kmlUrl = "";
    me.ALTITUDE_MODE = ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND;
    me.scaleX = 0.3;
    me.scaleY = 0.3;
    me.scaleZ = 0.3;
}
```

When I fetchKml, I store the kml model into my objectInfo.model:

```
    // Fetch a  KML file and show it
function finished(object, objInfo) {
    if (!object) {
        // wrap alerts in API callbacks and event handlers
        // in a setTimeout to prevent deadlock in some browsers
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Bad or null KML.');
        }, 0);
        return;
    }

    var modelPlacemark;
    walkKmlDom(object, function() {
        if (this.getType() == 'KmlPlacemark' && this.getGeometry()
                && this.getGeometry().getType() == 'KmlModel') {
            modelPlacemark = this;
        }
    });

    var model = modelPlacemark.getGeometry();

    objInfo.model = model;
```

This is how I call fetchKml

```
    shutter = new ModelInfo("Shutter"); //shutter is global variable

    shutter.kmlUrl = 'http://120.125.80.113/kml/student/space_shuttle_23_20110812a/space_shuttle_23_20110812a_SP.kmz';
    google.earth.fetchKml(ge, shutter.kmlUrl, function(obj) {
        finished(obj, shutter);
    });
```

But the problem is, after fetchKml finishes, I try to access **shutter.model**, **it is always null**, but when I access shutter.model **from within function finished**, **it is not null**

So my question is how did it happen? Is there anyway to store kml object in a global variable to modify its attribute later?

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

After several hrs trying to figure out why, I decided to use Firebug to debug the code and found out the reason. I still don't know why though.

The name I used for my variable "**shutter**" somehow isn't listed as a member of this page when I debugged using Firebug. When I changed it to **flying_obj** then everything is ok, I was able to store the kml object inside my **flying_obj.model**

Anyone knows what's wrong with the name "**shutter**" please explain it to me. It'd be great!!

Hans